# uft8_Encode or utf8_decode for accented characters in my mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting some records in my mysql database, and some have accented characters in their texts.

For example:

```
"PONTO : 09867, TABULETA : 08112, POSIÇÃO : 1 , MOTIVO : DIVULGACAO FADE/FAL"
```

Since i have to break this string down, i use this:

> $var = explode(", ", "PONTO : 09867, TABULETA : 08112, POSIÇÃO : 1 ,
>   MOTIVO : DIVULGACAO FADE/FAL"

I've tried this:

`$x = utf8_encode($var[2]);` - where the accented charater is

But it keeps getting me something like this:

```
POSIÃÂÃÂO : 2
```

Or

```
POSI?O : 2
```

I've tried decode as well, but still with no success. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the query result is ok just `explode` cuts the result in wrong places, thats because `explode` is not a multibyte function. You will have to do it with `preg_split`

```
$var= preg_split("/[\,]+/", "PONTO : 09867, TABULETA : 08112, POSIÇÃO : 1 , MOTIVO : DIVULGACAO FADE/FAL");
```

As we can see it is working correctly:
http://screencast.com/t/hW7Bo9vB

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'll see more about multibyte functions.

Answer (score 2):

Set connection encoding to UTF-8:

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
```

Take a look also at *set charset*.

**Update:**

It turns out it is a php issue, so one might take a look at **[Character sets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php)**

Comment: That would be in the connection settings? I'm actually a newbie on php...i don't know much. And honestly i really don't wanna mess around with their connection settings.